# Animating rotated UIView causes it to disappear

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, transform

I have a UIView that is 10 by 10, rotated 45 degrees to create a diamond shape.

Here is the code that rotates the view:

```
triangle = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, kUserViewHeight - 5, 10, 10)];
triangle.backgroundColor = [UIColor coolBlue];
//triangle.center = CGPointMake(5.0, 5.0);
triangle.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2 / 2);
```

I have purposely commented out the center value because this messes up setting the location of the view. I am completely aware that this is probably the issue.

The view shows up perfectly, but when I animate, the view moves where its supposed to but on the way, it disappears. When I get rid of the triangle.transform property, the view animates perfectly and does not disappear, but obviously it is just a square instead of the diamond.

Here is the animation code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:kAnimationInterval animations:^{

        triangle.frame = CGRectMake(115, kUserViewHeight - 5, 10, 10);

}];
```

Because I plan on moving the diamond shape around, setting the center becomes problematic. How can I both rotate the view and then animate it across the screen without it disappearing? Is there some kind of special way to calculate the center point to be exactly where I need it to be? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

yes what u did is u are rotating it 90 degree, as u said it is disappearing, do like this which may helps u 
one thing while u are animating order is important

```
 UIView* triangle = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, 25, 10, 10)];
 triangle.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:.4 blue:1 alpha:1]; // i am seeting diff color but not matter
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
  triangle.frame = CGRectMake(115, 20, 10, 10);//kUserViewHeight = 25 - 5 (i am assuming)        
 //it must be after setting the frame, now put rotation for 45 degree

 triangle.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/4);//it is M_PI/4 not M_PI /2

}];


 //  triangle.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/4); //you can put it hear or within the animation block
```

Hopes helps u :)